# Other language not supported to create PDF output in tcpdf

Tags: php

Use tcpdf but another language format is not supporting generating a PDF output     and shows blank. I used following code to pass values string $html but it shows blank I use fonts from other languages but there is no output.

```
<?php 

$html = "СЛУЖБА ЗА ЗАЈЕДНИЧКЕ ПОСЛОВЕ";//my string 

require_once('../plugins/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../plugins/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT,   PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Vision helpdesk');
$pdf->SetTitle("abc");
$pdf->SetSubject($ticket_details['subject']);
$pdf->SetKeywords('Vision helpdesk, PDF, '.$ticket_details['ticket_hash']);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$lg = Array();

$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output(abc.'.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Comment: solved this issue add below code

Comment: $fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('../plugins/tcpdf/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 9);
    $pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 20);

Answer (score 0):

Replace Set font with this
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '',9);